# Getting account lock status in MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql

I want to unlock an account in MS SQL Server. Before unlocking I have to check whether the account is locked or not - I only want to unlock if the account is locked.

Are there any SQL queries or stored procedures to get the "Locked" status of an SQL user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the statement I needed to use:

```
SELECT LOGINPROPERTY('loginname', 'IsLocked')
```